# Call + operation on collection elements in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Consider a data class with defined `+` operation:

```kotlin
data class Foo(
    val bar: Int = 0
) {
    fun plus(other: Foo) {
        return Foo(bar + other.bar)
    }
}
```

Now consider a List of these classes

```kotlin
val list: List<Foo>
```

eg.

```kotlin
val list = listOf(Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3))
val summed = list.summed() // Foo(6)
```

How to define an operation `summed` of type `List<Foo> -> Foo` in idiomatic way which takes all elements of array and call `.plus` operation to create a single element from them?

Comment: (Technically, that's not defining a `+` operation, only a `plus()` function, because it's not marked `operator fun`. That doesn't affect the main point of the question, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by

```kotlin
val runningReduceSum = numbers.reduce { sum, item -> sum + item }
```

described in

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-aggregate.html#fold-and-reduce

Comment: This is one of those cases where a function reference is more concise: `list.reduce(Foo::plus)`.

Answer (score 0):

As @gidds references in their comment, functions to use the `+` unary type operators, would require an operator keyword on the function.
Also, added the return type for the plus function.

Using extension functions in Kotlin, is the most appropriate manner to add the functionality to a List that you are looking for.

As a word of caution, implementing this function at the top level, would mean that it is in the entire scope of the application. It is generally a good idea to have extension functions scoped inside of an object or class context, just to keep things clean, and not accidentally expose functionality that is intended to be more internal.

```
data class Foo(val bar: Int = 0) {
    operator fun plus(other: Foo): Foo {
        return Foo(bar + other.bar)
    }
}

fun List<Foo>.summed(): Foo {
    val sum = fold(0) { acc, value -> acc + value.bar }

    return Foo(sum)
}

// This function could also be implemented as:
fun List<Foo>.summedAlso(): Foo = reduce(Foo::plus)

val fooList = listOf(
    Foo(1), Foo(3), Foo(5)
)

val output = fooList.summed()

println(output) // Foo(9)
```